# Find idle time from remote pc using c#

Tags: c#

I need to find out the idle time of remote pc  from server pc using c# application. I have a list of IP addresses and host names connected in Local Area Network. I want to find out idle time more then 30 min for each computer connected in LAN. I done it for local pc, but it not works for remote pc. here is my code for local pc.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

 private int GetIdleTime()
{
    LASTINPUTINFO lastone = new LASTINPUTINFO();
    lastone.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastone);
    lastone.dwTime = 0;

    int idleTime = 0;

    int tickCount = Environment.TickCount;
    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastone))
    {
        idleTime = tickCount - (int)lastone.dwTime;
        return idleTime;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd consider to use WMI. May be [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/0eec5824-c5a2-4299-92d5-109ec6fee897/) post will be helpfull

Comment: What do you mean it does not work on the remote pc ? Do you get an error ? What doesn't work properly ?

Comment: @evengyl is 100% correct, this is absolutely where WMI would come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this is not possible entirely for the local machine let alone a remote one.

> This function is useful for input idle detection. However,
>   GetLastInputInfo does not provide system-wide user input information
>   across all running sessions. Rather, GetLastInputInfo provides
>   session-specific user input information for only the session that
>   invoked the function.

You could however try one of the following:

- Have a process on each PC which you can query.
- Have a process on each
  PC reporting to your central process.
- Monitor remote PC processes to
  determine if the screen saver is active.

If you do not have terminal services deactivated, and the clients are xp or higher, you can also use

> ITerminalServicesSession.LastInputTime

For this you either use the Cassia libraries or p/invoke

> WTSQuerySessionInformation

Answer (score 1):

I use this remote WMI query:

```
object idleResult = Functions.remoteWMIQuery(machinename, "", "", "Select CreationDate From Win32_Process WHERE Name = \"logonUI.exe\"", "CreationDate", ref wmiOK);
```

Logonui.exe is the lockscreen. In business environments most systems lock when a user is idle.

You can translate the result like this in DateTime format

```
DateTime idleTime = Functions.ParseCIM_DATETIME((string)idleResult);
```

Where ParseCIM_DATETIME is this fucntion:

```
public static DateTime ParseCIM_DATETIME(string date)
    {
        //datetime object to store the return value
        DateTime parsed = DateTime.MinValue;

        //check date integrity
        if (date != null && date.IndexOf('.') != -1)
        {
            //obtain the date with miliseconds
            string newDate = date.Substring(0, date.IndexOf('.') + 4);

            //check the lenght
            if (newDate.Length == 18)
            {
                //extract each date component
                int y = Convert.ToInt32(newDate.Substring(0, 4));
                int m = Convert.ToInt32(newDate.Substring(4, 2));
                int d = Convert.ToInt32(newDate.Substring(6, 2));
                int h = Convert.ToInt32(newDate.Substring(8, 2));
                int mm = Convert.ToInt32(newDate.Substring(10, 2));
                int s = Convert.ToInt32(newDate.Substring(12, 2));
                int ms = Convert.ToInt32(newDate.Substring(15, 3));

                //compose the new datetime object
                parsed = new DateTime(y, m, d, h, mm, s, ms);
            }
        }

        //return datetime
        return parsed;
    }
```

The remote WMI Query function is as follows:

```
public static object remoteWMIQuery(string machine, string username, string password, string WMIQuery, string property, ref bool jobOK)
    {
        jobOK = true;
        if (username == "")
        {
            username = null;
            password = null;
        }
        // Configure the connection settings.
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Username = username; //could be in domain\user format
        options.Password = password;
        ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", machine));
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);

        // Try and connect to the remote (or local) machine.
        try
        {
            scope.Connect();
        }
        catch (ManagementException ex)
        {
            // Failed to authenticate properly.
            jobOK = false;
            return "Failed to authenticate: " + ex.Message;
            //p_extendederror = (int)ex.ErrorCode;
            //return Status.AuthenticateFailure;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            // Unable to connect to the RPC service on the remote machine.
            jobOK = false;
            return "Unable to connect to RPC service";
            //p_extendederror = ex.ErrorCode;
            //return Status.RPCServicesUnavailable;
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // User not authorized.
            jobOK = false;
            return "Error: Unauthorized access";
            //p_extendederror = 0;
            //return Status.UnauthorizedAccess;
        }

        try
        {
            ObjectQuery oq = new ObjectQuery(WMIQuery);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, oq);

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (property != null)
                {
                    return queryObj[property];
                }
                else return queryObj;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            jobOK = false;
            return "Error: " + e.Message;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this might be valid without RDP, as soon as remote desktop gets involved you additionally need to get session information from the undocumented `WinStationQueryInformationW` (see sources for Mimikatz and ProcessHacker for details on how to call it) to determine which sessions are active.  The `logonUI.exe` is still present if a user is logged on through RDP with an active session.  You can sometimes get `WINSTATIONINFOCLASS.LastInputTime` if you are lucky, but this is often empty if RDP is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the screensaver enabled I would suggest you check the CreateDate on the screensaver process and do a difference from the remote the createdate time and you get the idle time + the screensaver timeout

you might want to use WMI for this kind of thing

its a hack but it works